# The 'InitializeComponent' and '_FrameViews' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, xbap

I'm in the process of learning WPF, so in my case I have an xbap application and the code below is the code behind MainView.xaml.cs. Also, it was initially of a Page Type and I just changed it to UserControl recently because I need to deploy this app using ClickOnce.

List of errors:

1. The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context.
2. The name 'FrameViews' does not exist in the current context.

```
public partial class MainView : UserControl
   {
       public MainView()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           this.DataContext = MainViewModel.UniqueInstance;
           MainViewModel.UniqueInstance.FrameNavigationService = _FrameViews.NavigationService;

           _FrameViews.Unloaded +=new RoutedEventHandler(_FrameViews_Unloaded);
       }

       private void _FrameViews_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           _FrameViews.Content = null;
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @vasily.sib How do I remove these errors?

Comment: Pretty straightforward. Your errors says that this names _"does not exist in the current context"_ - so, I guess you need to declare them in your context or remove them:\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InitializeComponent()` is only available in MainWindow not in MainView
you need to write like that:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

and the `_FrameView` doesent exist you need to declare it